# Schemas and user rights

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have 2 schemas, lets say **sch1** and **sch2**. Each owned by different user.

I do want to grant **SELECT** rights on **sch2.MyTable** (but just this one object) to **sch1** procedures/views AND allow to reference **sch2.MyTable** in **sch1** foreign key constraints.

I do NOT want to make **sch2.MyTable** directly accessible to those, who uses **sch2** procedures/views, but want to allow indirect access.

Basically sch2 is much more important. Owners of sch2 have control of sch1 as well, but not vice a versa. On the other hand sch1 has some data that is dependant on sch2 and they should be able to see them and should not allow delete data from sch2, while sch1 still has some dependencies on them.

**Is that possible (maybe through synonyms)?**

For no it seems- no, not possible. Unless take off part about "Views and Constraints" OR "different schema owners".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look into using certificates to sign the stored procedures.  This will allow users to access anothers tables.

Comment: so- is should take off part about "Views and Constraints". Views cannot be signed, and constraints will not be possible to make if schema sch1 users are not able to access that table from sch2.

Comment: I believe that the DBA (or member of the db_owner fixed database role) would need to create the constraints.  The same probably applies to views.

Comment: wow, that really works! is sch1 and sch2 are owned and managed by different users and none of them have permissions to other schema tables, db_owner still can make constraints from one schema table to other schema table.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following answer will help:

```
Syntax:

GRANT <PERMISSION> ON <SCHEMA>.<TABLE NAME>(<COLUMN NAME>) TO <GRANTEE> .

DENY  <PERMISSION> ON <SCHEMA>.<TABLE NAME>(<COLUMN NAME>) TO <GRANTEE> .

REVOKE <PERMISSION> ON <SCHEMA>.<TABLE NAME>(<COLUMN NAME>) TO <GRANTEE> .

<PERMISSION> = SELECT | UPDATE | REFERENCES
```

You can check the privileges by using the information schema.

> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_PRIVILEGES

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this easily by just granting EXEC on the stored procedure(s) and SELECT on the view(s) to the user(s) you want to indirectly access the table. We do this in our office all the time, we don't grant permissions to underlying tables and only allow access to the underlying data through views/procedures.

Comment: If i give "Select" permission on table, the user is able to select data from table directly. Ownership chaining would solve this, but that does not work as well because schemas are owned by different users.